# Export and Import of Outlook Contact Groups Not Working

Tags: outlook

I created several outlook groups and now I want to export them and import to my other Outlook account on another computer.
The exported groups are stored either as .msg or as .txt files. 
However, when I send them to my other address and when I open a group, I get EMPTY message.
BUT if I send the contact to the e-mail address from which I created the contact groups than I can import them and I see all the e-mail addresses in the group.
Why does it not function in the other outlook with another e-mail account?

Can anyone help me with export import of contact groups? On google I haven't found either any solution nor any similar issue for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SO is for the programming questions. Secondly, save contacts in the vCard format or zip the MSG files first to prevent Outlook from converting them into embedded messages.